# Firebase send notifications to users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am trying to send notifications to some users that I have on my database on Firebase, I know that Firebase has a section related to notifications, but I just saw an example to how push notification directly from the Firebase website, I have an event in my app, when that event is created I want to send the notification to all users so basically this is the event:

```
public void createEventGame(View view){

        Match match = new Match(userId,gameEventNameTxt.getText().toString(),dateMatch);
        String key = myGameRef.push().getKey();
        myGameRef.child(key).setValue(match);


        /*if(radioMatchSelected){

        }*/

        if(radioEventSelected){
            final HashMap<String,Boolean> matches = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
            matches.put(key,true);


            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            final String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Log.d("sizebb",text);

            myRef.child(userId).child("FriendLists").child(text).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    long size = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

                    Log.d("sizebb",String.valueOf(size));
                    for(DataSnapshot s: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        friends.put(s.getKey(),false);
                    }
                    if(size < 10){
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "You need to have atleast 10 friends in your group, go to your friendlist and add some friends!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }

                    Event event = new Event(gameEventNameTxt.getText().toString(),hourWeek,userId,matches,friends,dayOfWeek);
                    myEventRef.child(event.getName()).setValue(event);

                    /*else{
                        friends.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(),true);
                    }*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });
```

Now how can i deal with notifications, is there any good tutorial talking about it? I can't find it, or do I need to deal with notifications with the database on firebase directly?

Comment: If my understanding of your scenario is correct, where `event` is something added to your Firebase DB, I think [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about the question, will try my best.

So you can send firebase notifications through console to all the users. You can also group users based on topics they subscribed and also to single devices (You need a token to send individual devices). [Firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). Also, you can send notifications from your program logic.

Look at the various types of notifications that you can send [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Another place to quick start with firebase is their github repo. Almost you can find a quick start project for everything. [Firebase Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/)

Answer (score 0):

Have all the friends you want to send the Notification to subscribe to a common topic.

When the event occurs, call the Firebase REST API and send the notification to this topic and all your users should get them. Notification tag or Data tag or both is upto your usecase. I prefer Data tag only so as to ensure that everything that happens stays in the code that i write and not system code.

What topic name you choose and which people subscribe is upto you. This should get you started.

Comment: so what you mean is, that the FIrebase push notification doesn't serve my use case?

Comment: You can use cloud functions if you want to handle the event on server side.... If you want to handle it on client side use the approach i specified and send notifications from client side to all other clients on an event